# Where is the aromatic ring in the pentacene molecule?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, aromatic-compounds

I have the following problem: I am given the coordinates of the atoms of a [pentacene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentacene) molecule ($\ce{C22H14}$), and I would like to find the ring where the aromatic bond is located. Is this possible? Or is the aromatic bond kind of simultaneously located across all rings?

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Comment: The whole system is aromatic

Comment: Maybe ixaixim is looking for the position of the only benzene ring which can be drawn (with three double bonds) among the five cycles of the pentacene molecule. Is it the point ?

Comment: @Maurice Then this is _any_ ring.

Comment: @ixaixim Possible if you can actually **read** the said coordinates, impossible otherwise. Can you? While we're at it, can you find the bond lengths?

Comment: @IvanNeretin yes, I can read the molecule coordinates. Yes, I can also find the interatomic distances.

Comment: Good. Then compare the C-C bond lengths in each ring. A single bond is 1.54 angstrom, a double bond is 1.34, an aromatic bond is 1.39, and you will probably observe something in between, leading to a not-very-satisfying answer "partially aromatic".

Comment: @IvanNeretin yes indeed I do! This oddity was in fact motivating my question. Thanks for explaining it the other way around, that is "the C-C bond lengths have all a mixed length, since the aromatic bond is in *any* ring", right?

Comment: My point about "any ring" was referring to **Maurice**'s approach, which is based on drawing structures by hand and **not** on actual bond lengths. Since you have the latter, you don't need the former. If the bond lengths in some ring were exactly equal, that ring could be called fully aromatic, but I guess that is not quite so, hence we may say that the rings are partially aromatic, and maybe that some rings are more aromatic than the others.

Comment: @IvanNeretin we can indeed have some rings more stabilized than others. And put this selectivity to good use.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clar's_rule

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have a chain of cumulated conjugated rings either the entire chain is aromatic or it isn't. In this case it is. There is no single aromatic ring.

However, that does not mean all rings are equally stabilized. In general, with three or more rings in the chain we generally see the end rings most resistant to addition reactions, so they show greater stability than the more addition-prone middle ring(s). Such is the case with not only with pentacene, with the third ring in the chain especially prone to breaking the conjugation, but also the simpler compound anthracene.

**Both ends against the middle**

The case of anthracene is instructive. Although this compound is aromatic, the middle ring is relatively easily saturated at the two central carbon atoms, like a conjugated alkene undergoing 1,4-addition. The reaction with magnesium in THF is an example:

[image]

The [magnesium anthracene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_anthracene), with its middle ring saturated, is used as an intermediate for production of reduced anthracene compounds and also magnesium hydride. In the latter case the anthracene is released in unreduced form, which can then be combined with more magnesium.

**2+2 becomes greater than 5**

Pentacene shows an extra form of middle-ring de-aromatization. From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentacene), we see that when an alkyl group such as methyl is substituted onto the middle ring, it spontaneously converts to a methylene group with the remaining aromatic rings now all "end" rings in naphthalene systems (reaction drawn by v8rik at English Wikipedia [source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:6-methylpentaceneEquilibrium.png#mw-jump-to-license)):

[image]