# Encoding molecule bond information in matrix form

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromaticity, machine-learning

I have the following problem: I have a [pentacene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentacene) molecule and would like to encode its bond information into a matrix form, to feed it later on to a Machine Learning (ML) algorithm (a Graph Neural Network, fyi).
The matrix has dimension $(36, 36)$ (since a pentacene molecule has $36$ atoms). Each entry $(i,j)$ represents the bond between atom $i$ with atom $j$.

My original idea was to encode a number depending on the bond type (e.g. single bond=1, double bond=2 and aromatic bond=1.5).
In my previous [post](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/169406/where-is-the-aromatic-ring-in-the-pentacene-molecule) though, I found out that the whole system is aromatic. Now my question would be: how could I encode this? Should I assign 1.5 to every bond?
I know this question might not have a definitive answer, but I am looking more at a way to justify my choices.

As a bonus: Do someone know of any ML paper where people encoded bond information?

Comment: Maybe this is not the right site to ask about this topic. However, I can suggest you two types of matrixes you can encode this information: the connectivity matrix (so just if atom i is linked to atom j); the distance matrix (so the arithmetic distance of atom i to atom j) which allow to bypass the bond-order problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :D I am however still curious if there is a way of using categorical information about the bond type.

Comment: @ixaixim, Have you checked out ECFP6 fingerprinting? If you have your molecule as a .mol2 or .pdb file, you would be able to generate this fingerprint using RDKit, which encodes the connectivity information in a 2048 bit vector. This fingerprint is theoretically not unique, but such collisions have been shown to be rare.

Comment: I only have the positions of the molecule atoms. Nothing more.

Comment: @ixaixim If you have the positions, and if you know the which atoms the positions correspond to, you can generate the .pdb file, and then continue.

Comment: As you have learned, in actual molecules, single and double bonds are not exclusive categories. Rather, bond order is a continuum for which one can use various metrics. How to best represent it likely depends heavily on what you are using the machine learning for.

Answer (score 1):

There are, of course, multiple ways to encode the bonding graph into a matrix, for example:

- Since you have pentacene, all bonds could be typed as aromatic
- Since you have the 3D positions, you could encode the exact atom-atom distance / bond length
- As some have mentioned in the comments, you can use atom environments (e.g., fingerprints) of the two atoms to encode information .. for example as (C.ar-C.ar).

All three methods have been used in the chemistry ML literature.

The first is more useful if you do not have accurate 3D coordinates, since it only requires the molecular structure (e.g., SMILES, 2D depiction, etc.).

It's hard to know which encoding would be the most useful -- in general one must try a few possible descriptors to find the best for your particular task.